# Symfony2: asset version with assetic

Tags: symfony, version, assets, assetic

I need to manage my javascripts files version, to avoid the user from using an out of date file.

I my config file, I defined :

```
assets_version: v2.1
```

It works well when I use:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="{{ asset('bundles/mybundle/js/my_js.js') }}"></script>
```

But if I also need to use the javascripts tags like:

```
{% javascripts
'bundles/my_bundle/js/js1.js'
'bundles/my_bundle/js/js2.js'
 %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

But then the version is not applied. Also tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset(asset_url) }}"></script>
```

But this duplicates the base path of the file. What is the good way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using:

```
{% javascripts
    'bundles/my_bundle/js/js1.js'
    'bundles/my_bundle/js/js2.js'
 %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

You will need to use the production controller (app.php) (without debug) to see the asset version appended. (you have to dump your assets too)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://assets2.yoursite.com/js/youjs.js?v2.1"></script>
```

In dev mode you probably have something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app_dev.php/js/js1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app_dev.php/js/js2.js"></script>
```

Comment: You mean with <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script> ?

Comment: No.. using app_dev.php (dev mode) or app.php controller. (prod mode)

Comment: I have modified my answer.

Comment: @Rolintocour did you gave a try ?